# MAAS: How to login to deployed node via terminal NOT via ssh

Tags: networking, login, maas

after deploying my nodes, I need to access several of them to debug their networking configuration. Since this is obviousely broken, ssh is not available and I need to login at the server directly.

OK, the only user available on the node is ubuntu and an empty password does not work (I assume this was disabled for security reasons). Simple question: Is it possible to access the node directly not via network? Is there a default password at all? Or, is ist generated randomly?

Best,
Sebastian